# Indicator lines not working in menu navigation

Tags: javascript, css, html, fullpage.js

I've been on StackOverflow for some days now trying to make a line indicator in my navigation menu. Below I've posted my 3 sections of code (HTML, CSS, JS). Keep in mind that I am using the fullpage.js script for the base structure of my website.

I've coded the HTML navigation section with an aside-navigation class and defined the menu selector in fullpage configuration (bottom of HTML code).

I've also created a JS called `Navigation` with a function that makes the line beginning at each section, reducing it at the end and then continues to the next section, but this doesn't seem to work.

For some reason something related to the selectors of my CSS are not working with fullpage.js? I'm confused; if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great!

I have removed some css code that is beyond the scope of the question due to the post restrictions. I'm sorry for the huge post; just trying to show exactly what i have done.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE ALL!

```js
// NAVIGATION INDICATOR ANIMATION //

    Navigation = function (e, t) {
        function i(t) {
            this.scrollController = t, this.navLinks = [[e("#link-section-what-we-do"), !1], [e("#link-section-our-approach"), !1], [e("#link-section-who-we-are"), !1], [e("#link-section-clients"), !1], [e("#link-section-contact"), !1]], this.navScenes = [], this.init()
        }
        return i.prototype.init = function () {
            var i = this;
            t.setTimeout(function () {
                i.initScrollMagic()
            }, 500), e(t).resize(function () {
                i.refreshScenes()
            })
        }, i.prototype.initScrollMagic = function () {
            var t = this;
            this.navScenes.push(new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#section-product",
                duration: e("#section-product").outerHeight(!0)
            }).setClassToggle("#link-section-what-we-do", "active").addTo(this.scrollController).on("progress", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 0)
            }).on("enter", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 0, !0)
            }).on("end, leave", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgressEnd(e, 0)
            })), this.navScenes.push(new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#the-variety",
                duration: e("#the-variety").outerHeight(!0)
            }).setClassToggle("#link-section-our-approach", "active").addTo(this.scrollController).on("progress", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 1)
            }).on("enter", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 1, !0)
            }).on("end, leave", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgressEnd(e, 1)
            })), this.navScenes.push(new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#section-who-we-are",
                duration: e("#section-who-we-are").outerHeight(!0)
            }).setClassToggle("#link-section-who-we-are", "active").addTo(this.scrollController).on("progress", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 2)
            }).on("enter", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 2, !0)
            }).on("end leave", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgressEnd(e, 2)
            })), this.navScenes.push(new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#section-clients",
                duration: e("#section-clients").outerHeight(!0)
            }).setClassToggle("#link-section-clients", "active").addTo(this.scrollController).on("progress", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 3)
            }).on("enter", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 3, !0)
            }).on("end, leave", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgressEnd(e, 3)
            })), this.navScenes.push(new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#section-contact",
                duration: e("#section-contact").outerHeight(!0)
            }).setClassToggle("#link-section-contact", "active").addTo(this.scrollController).on("progress", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 4)
            }).on("enter", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgress(e, 4, !0)
            }).on("end, leave", function (e) {
                t.scrollProgressEnd(e, 4)
            }))
        }, i.prototype.refreshScenes = function () {
            for (var t = 0; t < this.navScenes.length; t++) {
                var i = e(this.navScenes[t].triggerElement()).outerHeight(!0);
                this.navScenes[t].duration(i)
            }
        }, i.prototype.scrollProgress = function (e, t, i) {
            var n = 44,
                r = this,
                s = this.navLinks[t][0].find(".nav-indicator");
            i ? (this.navLinks[t][1] = !0, TweenMax.set(s, {
                height: 0
            }), TweenMax.to(s, .2, {
                height: (1 - e.progress) * n + "px",
                ease: Power3.easeIn,
                onComplete: function () {
                    r.navLinks[t][1] = !1
                }
            })) : this.navLinks[t][1] || s.css("height", (1 - e.progress) * n + "px")
        }, i.prototype.scrollProgressEnd = function (e, t) {
            var i = this.navLinks[t][0].find(".nav-indicator");
            this.navLinks[t][1] = !1, i.removeAttr("style")
        }, i
    }(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
  /******** NAVIGATION **********/

    .aside-navigation {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 4;
        display: none
    }

    .aside-navigation.hidden {
        display: none
    }

    .lt-ie9 .aside-navigation {
        display: block
    }

    .aside-navigation ul {
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate3d(0, -12rem, 0);
        transform-origin: center center;
        z-index: 200
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li {
        color: #909090;
        margin-right: 2.75rem;
        transition: color .5s;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li:hover {
        color: #77919f
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li:last-child {
        margin-right: 0
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: .75rem 0;
        font-size: .75rem
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li a:active,
    .aside-navigation ul li a:focus {
        outline: none
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li.active {
        color: #c9a739
    }

    .aside-navigation ul li.active .nav-indicator {
        background: #000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3.4375rem;
        left: 50%;
        height: 2.75rem;
        width: .125rem;
        margin-left: -1px;
        z-index: 999
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:48em) {
            .aside-navigation {
            display: block
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:90em) {
        .aside-navigation ul {
            transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-14.875rem)
        }
        .aside-navigation ul li a {
            font-size: 1rem;
            padding: .75rem 0
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-height:41.875em) {
        .aside-navigation ul {
            transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-4.625rem)
        }
        .aside-navigation ul li {
            margin-right: 0
        }
        .aside-navigation ul li a {
            font-size: 0;
            width: 2.75rem;
            height: 2.75rem;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block
        }
        .aside-navigation ul li a:before {
            line-height: 3.125rem;
            content: '⋅';
            font-size: 3.125rem
        }

    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fullpage.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/midnight.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="body">
        <nav id="small-logo-layer" class="small-logo-layer"><a href="#home" class="small-logo">
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="" height="100%"
                     viewBox="0 0 149.3 170.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 149.3 170.7;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <title>brand-logo</title>
                    <g id="logo-small" fill="#FEFEFE">
                        <path d="M84.3,168.2c0,0-0.2-42.9-1.9-54.4c-0.2-1.1-0.7-2.2-1.2-3.2c-0.9-0.9-2-1.6-3.1-2.1
                                 c-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.3-0.9c-0.5-0.5-20.8-18.6-34-43.5c-5.5-10.4-13.4-25.6-8.2-28.5c4.2-2.4,28.2,13.3,35,22.9
                                 c11.9,16.8,16.6,37.5,17,50.7c0.1,15.7,1.2,43.3,1.3,59 M82.8,106.7c3.2,1.3-1.6-12.1-2.4-15.7c-2-8.6-5.8-18-16.6-33.2
                                 c-7.2-10.1-25.6-21.6-27.9-19.2C29.9,44.6,65.5,99.5,82.8,106.7z"/>
                        <path d="M118.4,66.8c0.3,2.1,0.7,14.4-4.7,22.8c-8.1,12.6-20.1,16.8-25.8,21.3c-2.4,1.9-5.1,6.3-5,3.7
                                 c0.6-13.8,20.6-30.7,20.6-30.7C114,72.8,117.5,60.7,118.4,66.8z"/>

                        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.8217 -0.5699 0.5699 0.8217 -24.873 28.4332)" cx="33" cy="54" rx="2.3" ry="2.3"/>

                        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.8217 -0.5699 0.5699 0.8217 -20.6115 72.7065)" cx="105.9" cy="69.3" rx="3.4" ry="3.4"/>

                        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.8217 -0.5699 0.5699 0.8217 -48.7922 74.6922)" cx="95" cy="115.3" rx="3.9" ry="3.9"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <g id="logo-small" fill="#FEFEFE">
                            <path d="M149.3,170.7H0V0h149.3V170.7z M5,165.7h139.3V5H5V165.7z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
                </a>
        </nav>
        <section class="aside-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="link-section-what-we-do"><a class="click-to-scroll active" href="#the-product">The Product<span class="nav-indicator"></span></a></li>
                <li id="link-section-our-approach"><a class="click-to-scroll" href="#the-variety">The Variety<span class="nav-indicator"></span></a></li>
                <li id="link-section-who-we-are"><a class="click-to-scroll" href="#the-diet">The Diet<span class="nav-indicator"></span></a></li>
                <li id="link-section-clients"><a class="click-to-scroll" href="#about-us">About us<span class="nav-indicator"></span></a></li>
                <li id="link-section-contact"><a class="click-to-scroll" href="#contact-us">Contact us<span class="nav-indicator"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="section-home" class="section" data-anchor="home" data-midnight="gone"></div>
            <div id="section-product" class="section" data-anchor="the-product" data-midnight="dark">
                <div class="hsContent text-index" data-center="transform: translateY(0px);" data-bottom-top="opacity: 1" data--100-bottom="opacity:1;transform: translateY(0px);" data-center-top="opacity: 1;transform: translateY(212px);" data-anchor-target="#the-product">
                    <h2>THE<br/> PRODUCT</h2>
                    <h3>My product is awesome</h3>
                    <div class=description>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                        <div data-modal-id=product class="read_more_text ">Read more</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vertical-line bez"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="section-variety" class="section" data-anchor="the-variety" data-midnight="white"></div>
            <div id="section-diet" class="section" data-anchor="the-diet" data-midnight="dark"></div>
            <div id="section-about" class="section" data-anchor="about-us" data-midnight="white"></div>
            <div id="section-contact" class="section" data-anchor="contact-us" data-midnight="white"></div>


            <div data-modal=product>
                <div class=modal-container>
                    <div class=close-custom-modal><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio=xMidYMid width=65 height=65 viewBox="0 0 65 65">
                    <image xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" width=65 height=65 />
                    </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class=text-container>
                        <h2>THE
                            <BR/> PRODUCT</h2>
                        <h3>My Product is awesome</h3>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                // Start midnight
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // Change this to the correct selector.
                    $('.small-logo-layer').midnight();
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#wrapper').fullpage({

                        //Navigation
                        menu: '.aside-navigation',
                        lockAnchors: false,
                        anchors: ['home', 'the-product', 'the-variety', 'the-diet', 'about-us', 'contact-us'],
                        navigation: false,
                        navigationPosition: 'left',
                        navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
                        showActiveTooltip: false,
                        slidesNavigation: false,
                        slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

                        //Scrolling
                        css3: true,
                        scrollingSpeed: 1000,
                        autoScrolling: false,
                        fitToSection: false,
                        fitToSectionDelay: 500,
                        scrollBar: false,
                        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                        easingcss3: 'ease',
                        loopBottom: false,
                        loopTop: false,
                        loopHorizontal: false,
                        continuousVertical: false,
                        continuousHorizontal: false,
                        scrollHorizontally: false,
                        interlockedSlides: false,
                        dragAndMove: false,
                        offsetSections: false,
                        resetSliders: false,
                        fadingEffect: false,
                        scrollOverflow: false,
                        scrollOverflowReset: false,
                        scrollOverflowOptions: null,
                        touchSensitivity: 15,
                        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
                        bigSectionsDestination: null,

                        //Accessibility
                        keyboardScrolling: true,
                        animateAnchor: true,
                        recordHistory: true,

                        //Design
                        controlArrows: false,
                        verticalCentered: true,
                        sectionsColor: ['#ccc', '#fff'],
                        responsiveWidth: 0,
                        responsiveHeight: 0,
                        responsiveSlides: false,
                        parallax: true,
                        parallaxOptions: {
                            type: 'cover',
                            percentage: 30,
                            property: 'translate'
                        },
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                WebFontConfig = {
                    google: {
                        families: ['Roboto:300,400,500,900']
                    }
                };
                (function() {
                    var wf = document.createElement('script');
                    wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
                    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
                    wf.async = 'true';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
                })();
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var s = skrollr.init();
            </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: There's way too much code in your question, you will hardly get any answer like that. Try to reduce the problem to the minimum and reduce any unnecessary code that is not directly related with your problem. Then, you'll also get far more answers if you provide an isolated reproduction in jsfiddle.net or codepen. (use very little code)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will try! to do a demo